# Unable to update or create records using POST with strong_parameters and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I can't figure out why my database records are not getting updated, or new records created, for that matter, when I POST from a form.

I am able to manually populate the database and create relationships:

```
contact = Contact.first
command = Command.find(3)
contact.host_notification_commands << command
```

And I am also able to load this data info my form. What I can't figure out is how to update or add new records. Everything i've tried so far has failed.

I have 3 models - `Command`, `Contact` and joined `CommandsContact`. `commands_contacts` join table is holing an extra attribute `:notification_type`, which could either be set to *host* or *service*, and my `Contact` model has 2 extra relationships setup to i can access `:host_notification_commands` and `:service_notification_commands`. This gives me an ability to do things like `Contact.fist.host_notification_commands` or `Contact.find(3).service_notification_commands.`

It appears that no `UPDATE` or `INSERT` queries are ever firing up from the controller, when I to proper POST and I can't figure out how to debug that.

**Models**

```
class Command < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :commands_contacts
  has_many :contacts, :through => :commands_contacts

end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :commands_contacts
    has_many :commands, :through => :commands_contacts

    has_many :host_notification_commands, -> { where commands_contacts: { :notification_type => 'host' } },
            :through => :commands_contacts,
            :class_name => 'Command', 
            :source => :command

    has_many :service_notification_commands, -> { where commands_contacts: { notification_type: 'service' } },
            :through => :commands_contacts,
            :class_name => 'Command', 
            :source => :command

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :commands, :host_notification_commands, :service_notification_commands

end

class CommandsContact < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :command
    belongs_to :contact

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :command

end
```

And after this everything falls apart.

**Controller**

Due to the fact that I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I have to append `_attributes` to the names of my nested objects - `:host_notification_commands` and `:service_notification_commands`. I'll change my form to submit it that way, but simple re-assignment works for an example sake.

```
def update
    contact = Contact.find_by_id(params[:id])
    contact.update(safe_params)
end    

private
def safe_params

    params[:contact][:host_notification_commands_attributes] = params[:contact][:host_notification_commands]
    params[:contact][:service_notification_commands_attributes] = params[:contact][:service_notification_commands]

    params.require(:contact)
        .permit(:contact_name, :host_notification_commands_attributes => [:id, :command_name, :command_line, :command_description],
                :service_notification_commands_attributes => [:id, :command_name, :command_line, :command_description])
end
```

Updating existing record results in:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Command with ID=2 for Contact with ID=1>
```

Of course it does not exist! I am trying to create this relationship!

Adding a new one, I get:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Command with ID=1 for Contact with ID=>
```

Absolutely correct. The user haven't even been created yet and relationship is not established with the commands, why is Rails trying to find it???

I am also not seeing any update or insert queries being logged in the rails console, so i guess its not even getting to that point...

```
D, [2015-01-20T18:01:30.336669 #95542] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-01-20T18:01:30.338971 #95542] DEBUG -- :   Command Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `commands`.* FROM `commands` INNER JOIN `commands_contacts` ON `commands`.`id` = `commands_contacts`.`command_id` WHERE `commands_contacts`.`contact_id` = 1 AND `commands_contacts`.`notification_type` = 'host' AND `commands`.`id` IN (1, 3)
D, [2015-01-20T18:01:30.340555 #95542] DEBUG -- :   Command Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `commands`.* FROM `commands` INNER JOIN `commands_contacts` ON `commands`.`id` = `commands_contacts`.`command_id` WHERE `commands_contacts`.`contact_id` = 1 AND `commands_contacts`.`notification_type` = 'service' AND `commands`.`id` IN (4, 2)
D, [2015-01-20T18:01:30.341501 #95542] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Command with ID=2 for Contact with ID=1>
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

What am i missing over here?

**EDIT:** I guess i could abandon the idea of using `strong_parameters`, parse all POST params and then manually populate the database, but thats not very Rails-y.

**EDIT #2:** Including params posted to the controller.

Data coming in as `params[:contact]` from the form

```
{
                     "contact_name" => "joe-user",
       "host_notification_commands" => [
        [0] {
                             "id" => 1,
                   "command_name" => "host-notify-by-email",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify",
            "command_description" => "Host Alert",
                     "created_at" => "2015-01-19T17:24:12.000Z",
                     "updated_at" => "2015-01-21T03:29:03.000Z"
        },
        [1] {
                             "id" => 2,
                   "command_name" => "host-notify-by-pager",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify-pager",
            "command_description" => "Host Alert by Pager",
                     "created_at" => "2015-01-19T17:24:33.000Z",
                     "updated_at" => "2015-01-19T17:24:33.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "service_notification_commands" => [
        [0] {
                             "id" => 4,
                   "command_name" => "service-notify-by-email",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/service-notify",
            "command_description" => "Service Alert",
                     "created_at" => "2015-01-19T17:24:44.000Z",
                     "updated_at" => "2015-01-19T17:24:44.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

After going through `strong_parameters` it becomes this:

Essentially the same thing, only with `created_at` and `updated_at` stripped and 
`_attributes` appended to the attribute names, so it works with `accept_nested_attributes_for`

```
{
                                "contact_name" => "joe-user",
       "host_notification_commands_attributes" => [
        [0] {
                             "id" => 1,
                   "command_name" => "host-notify-by-email",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify",
            "command_description" => "Host Alert"
        },
        [1] {
                             "id" => 2,
                   "command_name" => "host-notify-by-pager",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify-pager",
            "command_description" => "Host Alert by Pager"
        }
    ],
    "service_notification_commands_attributes" => [
        [0] {
                             "id" => 4,
                   "command_name" => "service-notify-by-email",
                   "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/service-notify",
            "command_description" => "Service Alert"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT #3:** I have enabled MySQL query logging but I do not see `UPDATE`/`INSERT` queries executed at all. How can i debug why `contact.update(safe_params)` is not doing anything?

**EDIT #4:** As a simple test without AngularJS or POST being in the equation, I made a simple rake tasks that defines a JSON object and tries to update the db. I am getting the same issue, so Im pretty convinced the issue is somewhere in my models... but where???

Please take a look at this Gist https://gist.github.com/pruchai/6afe74b170da2a3d307f

Comment: Attaching your view code and maybe even a screenshot of the parameters hitting the action from your terminal would be really helpful in answering your question

Comment: @Jay: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question to include data posted to Rails. My view is an Angular template. I am not using Rails views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a form and using `nested_fields_for` your form-structure is built correctly. So ideally you would try first do it the "old fashioned way", check what is pushed to the server and mimick that.

So generally I do not do this by hand, but I maintain a gem to handle nested forms (cocoon), so if I am not mistaken, for the `accepts_nested_attributes` to work, the parameters have to look as follows:

```
{
    "contact_name" => "joe-user",
    "host_notification_commands_attributes" => {
      "0" => {
        "id" => 1,
        "command_name" => "host-notify-by-email",
        "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify",
        "command_description" => "Host Alert"
      },
      "1" => {
        "id" => 2,
        "command_name" => "host-notify-by-pager",
        "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/host-notify-pager",
        "command_description" => "Host Alert by Pager"
      }
    },
    "service_notification_commands_attributes" => {
      "0" => {
        "id" => 4,
        "command_name" => "service-notify-by-email",
        "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/service-notify",
        "command_description" => "Service Alert"
      }, 
      "12342233444444" => {
        "command_name" => "service-notify-by-email",
        "command_line" => "/usr/local/bin/service-notify",
        "command_description" => "Service Alert"
      }
    }
  }
```

So instead of an array the `.._attributes` should contain a hash. The key is just the position in the (existing) array, I asuume. In cocoon I fill this *dummy index* with some large number derived from the current time. I assume this order should correspond to the default order for the relation. But if you hand down the "id" field, it is also possible rails uses that. Not sure. To destroy an existing element, you have to set the `_destroy` attribute (and allow it in the strong parameters as well).

Imho for new items the `id` should be empty, otherwise rails will assume the item exists (as generally ids are not generated on the client side).

Comment: Hm... This is interesting. Documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html says nothing about hash keys and none of the examples show them. It even goes on to mention that `Nested attributes for an associated collection can also be passed in the form of a hash of hashes instead of an array of hashes`, but en example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms specifically shows hash keys, as you mentioned. I am going to give this a try to day and let you know if that solved the issue.

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately. It does not matter if i submit a hash or an array. It get the same result. Also, `safe_params.permitted?` and `Contact.new(safe_params[:host_notification_commands]).valid?` both return `true` in either case.

Comment: Just tested in a real rails app :) Rails imho always posts a hash. The key is the position in the association, imho, and for new items fill in something large (default rails fills in a string like `new_association_name` for new records). Also note: when you give an `id`, rails will assume it exists. If the nested item is new, I presume you should not fill in an id.

Comment: I made a simple Rake task just to test by removing Angular and POST out of equation. I am convinced that the issue is somewhere within my models, rather than having something to do with the structure of the data. Please take a look https://gist.github.com/pruchai/6afe74b170da2a3d307f

Comment: Ok, I added a comment there: check that the existing command is indeed a host-notification. Otherwise it will not find it. If it should be a new command, leave id empty.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've added another comment to the Gist

Comment: Ah: you are trying to link _existing_ commands with contacts, right? In that case you should not be filling the `host_notification_commands`, but you should be filling the join-table `command_contacts` instead.

Comment: Correct, but *i am* filling `command_contacts` via  `host_notification_commands`. Added another comment to the gist to demonstrate it.

Comment: I am a bit offended. I know how relations work in rails. FIlling in via `host_notification_commands` only works if you are creating _new_ commands. If you are reusing existing commands you have to fill in `command_contacts` directly and point to an existing `id` yourself. There are two things: 1) the commands you are linking exist, but are not linked through the command-contacts table, so you get the `not found` error. So either you create _new_ commands, and link them in one go, _or_ you re-use existing commands, but then you need to fill in the `command_contacts` table instead.

Comment: My apologies. I had no intentions to offend you. This was a part of my misunderstanding of the framework. I was under the impression that Rails would establish the relationship automatically if it does not exist. I now realize that its not true and I have to work around it.  This answers my question. Thank you for your help.